# Помогите разобраться со слайдером

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

Доброго времени. Друзья помогите пожалуйста. Мой слайдер нереально много жрет оперативной памяти в чем дело?

http://jsbin.com/qedojilu/11/edit

```
$(function(){
    //Создаем функцию omenaSlider
    function omenaSlider(){
    //Инициализируем переменную счетчик  
    var i = 1;
    //Время показа одного слайдера  
    var sek = 16000; 
    //Подсчитываем количество слайдов
    var elements = $(".stuffing").size();
    //Умнажаем кол-во слайдов на время для зацикливания  
    var sek2 = elements*sek;
    //Запускаем функцию omenaSlider  
    var loop = setInterval(omenaSlider,sek2);
    //Останавливаем слайдер по клику  
      $(".pause").click(function(){
        clearInterval(loop);
        $(".pause").css("display","none");
        $(".play").css("display","block");
      });
    //Запускаем слайдер по клику   
      $(".play").click(function(){
        omenaSlider();
        $(".play").css("display","none");
        $(".pause").css("display","block");
      }); 
    (function(){
      function threed(){
        slide.css({"transform":"rotateY(0deg)"});
      }
      function threed2(){
        slide.css({"backgroundSize":"120%"});
      }
      if(i<=elements){
                      var slide = $(".stuffing");
                      slide.css("transform","rotateY(30deg)");
                      slide.css({"backgroundSize":"100%"});
                      $('.stuffing').hide();
                      var count = "#slide"+i;
                      i++;
                      $(count).slideDown();
                      setTimeout(threed,1);
                      setTimeout(threed2,1000);
                      var loop = setTimeout(arguments.callee, sek);
                      $(".pause").click(function(){
                        clearInterval(loop);
                      });
                    }   
    })();

  }
  omenaSlider();});
```

Comment: вы его в цикле инициализируете ?

    var loop = setInterval(omenaSlider,sek2);

и потом еще вешаете click столько раз сколько проинициализировали

   $(".pause").click(function(){

Comment: не догоняю) ладно завтра разберусь голова не варит уже) весь день сижу.

Comment: напишите перед `clearInterval(loop);` 

    console.log('нажали на паузу');

подождите с минуту, и нажмите на кнопку паузы, вы получите более двух сообщений сразу.

Comment: и что это значит я не могу понять)? до меня трудно доходит)

Comment: это ответ на ваш вопрос, много жрет.

Comment: вы не могли бы меня направить? что я делаю не так? как его упростить?

Comment: @Сашка, я все сказал что мог, просто не вешайте click в обработчике `setInterval()`, зачем вы это делаете я не понимаю.

Comment: Тогда слайдер останавливается не на том же месте где я его останавливаю. А доходит до последнего и только тогда вот посмотрите пожалуйста http://jsbin.com/qedojilu/10/edit